# CSS Image zoom-to-fill?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a website with a full viewport image like so

[image]

The background image takes up the entire container beneath the Nav Bar.

I want to make it so that on mobile, when I view the image, it's zoomed in/centered such that the image isn't distorted and I'm still able to see some of it as a background... I'm probably not explaining it properly, I'm not fluent in design, but I think this mockup speaks for itself

[image]

The red shows the original image boundary, and the blue is the mobile viewport. I want the image to be "cropped"/zoomed on mobile. How do I do this with CSS? Thanks

Edit: To clarify what I've tried, I don't believe I can use `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center`. My current setup is with a React Bootstrap Carousel. The Carousel component takes an `<img>` attribute, so I'm trying to modify the styling of the image. From what I've read, the background-size/position attribute only apply to the `<html>` tag's style, and it doesn't work based on my experience with attempting this suggestion.

For example, in my `homepage.scss` I have the following

```
.fullImage {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And I apply it to the image in the Carousel

```
<Carousel.Item interval={5000}>
  <img
    className="fullImage"
    src="/images/home/banner/img1.jpg"
  />
</Carousel.Item>
```

Only for the effect on Mobile to look something like this:

[image]

where the intended effect is supposed to be something like the middle image, where the image isn't actually scrollable outside of the viewport and instead has a fixed size and "zoomed-in" view on a smaller screen.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly so just to be sure: `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center` do not achieve what you want?

Comment: I should've clarified what I've tried so far. From what I've read/attempted, the background-size/position attribute only apply to the `<html>` style. I have the images on a Bootstrap Carousel, and the component takes an `<img>`. So I'm attempting to apply this styling to `<img>` and I haven't had much success

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to keep the `img` element (without background-image), I would choose [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit). This solution works only in [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=object-fit).

```css
* { margin: 0; } /* just some reset */
.header { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; overflow: hidden; }
img { width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080"/>
</div>
```

*However, ideally I would choose [src-sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/srcset) and replace the image for the mobile with the cropped one so that it does not load unnecessarily large.*

Comment: `src-set` only chooses between pre-specified images. My concern is that it won't scale "dynamically" unless I have a lot of images to pick from. I can try your suggestion though and get back to you on that

Comment: This didn't work either, I tried `.homeBanner{ height: 100vh; width: 100vw; overflow: hidden; } .fullImage{ width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; }` and applied `<Carousel.Item className ='homeBanner'>` and `<img className='fullImage>` as to not mess with default header and container classes, and it threw off the styling for the whole website

Comment: Well it's hard to debug something what we can't run but as you can see attached example works fine.