# Overriding React Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I need help figuring out how to override React Bootstrap's carousel. I made a [post a few hours ago here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71471056/css-image-zoom-to-fill). To summarize, I wanted to create a fullscreen header image that scales appropriately on mobile.

[image]

[image]

The red shows the original image boundary, and the blue is the mobile viewport. The intended effect being the image isn't actually scrollable outside of the viewport, and instead has a fixed size and "zoomed-in" view on a smaller screen.

After taking in the feedback from my first post, I came to realize the issue lies entirely with `React Bootstrap`.

I went back to the drawing board and commented out all `<Carousel>` components, and just had my `Home` component return a rendered `<div>` with the following class configuration:

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="firstImage"></div>
      // <Carousel fade>
      //   <Carousel.Item interval={5000}>
      //   </Carousel.Item>
      // </Carousel>
  );
}
-------------
.firstImage{
    background-image: url('../../public/images/home/banner/img1.JPG'); 
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This gives the desired effect on both desktop and mobile
[image]

[image]

Now let's toss this `<div>` in the `<Carousel>` component.

```
function Home() {
  return (
      <Carousel fade>
        <Carousel.Item interval={5000}>
          <div className="firstImage"></div>
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
  );
}
```

Now, this happens on Desktop. The image is no longer visible, it disappears off the viewport, and the `Carousel` toggles are way up by the Nav Bar. It doesn't matter if I modify the CSS styling to just be the background image and height modifier. It all produces the same behavior.

```
.firstImage{
    background-image: url('../../public/images/home/banner/img1.JPG'); 
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

The Carousel is just a container, right? Why is this happening? Clearly some styles are being overwritten/clashing with the default behavior. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.